# Running jQuery tabs in JSFiddle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jsfiddle

I am new to jQuery and JSFiddle and tried doing a simple exercise on appendTo's site for manipulating the DOM: http://learn.appendto.com/lesson/dom-manipulation-101#exercise

I am trying to run the following code in JSFiddle and am not getting the expected tabbed behavior. Am I supposed to include something in the CSS to initialize the jQuery tabs widget?

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/albertc44/KhwZS/565/

Comment: You need to include a jQueryUI theme under "Add Resources"

Comment: Try include this "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" is a jquery ui css from a cdn. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KhwZS/567/

Comment: @Edward really good, why you don't post this as an answer... i could do that now ;) But i think you have to get the reputation points for that. I will upvote your answer... if you post one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved from a comment.

Is only a styling issue; try to include this
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css
in your current fiddle.
Is a jQuery Ui css included from a cdn.
Bere is your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/KhwZS/567/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Edward. How are the "Resources" different from the "Frameworks" at the top left of JSFiddle? I thought by including jQuery UI 1.8.9 it would load the proper library for styling.

Comment: By adding a "Framework" you include a desired js framework, but correctly not a proper css. Here is a deep documentation of the usage of jsfiddle http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#choose-framework

Comment: Ok, then to close the question mark the answer with the green check. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the CSS - the tabs() method is actually working but you dont see the desired style :

http://jsfiddle.net/KhwZS/568/

this shows you the correct look - as I have added the css to the jsfiddle as a resource